# Can I Map through an object in angular?

Tags: angular

I have been able to get data from a swagger endpoint, it displays on the console but throws an error whenever I try to loop through it and display its properties on the template view.

I get an error as shown below in the red area:
[image: Object Object error]

in the component.ts the data is passed through a service and console.logged:

```
export class CompanyDialogComponent  implements OnInit{

  taskpilot!: IGetTaskPilot[];

  constructor( private domainService: DomainService) {}
    ngOnInit(): void {
    
        this.domainService.getTaskPilot().subscribe({
            next:(response) => {
                this.taskpilot = response;
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            },
        });
    }
}
```

on the template:

```
<div *ngFor="let taskpilot of taskpilot">
    <div class="flex items-center px-5 my-3">
        <!-- <img [src]="mock_companies.img" width="20px" /> -->
        <span class="ml-4">
            <h2>{{ taskpilot.companies }}</h2>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like your `getTaskPilot()` returns an object and not an array, yet you assign it to `taskpilot`, which is typed `IGetTaskPilot[]`. You should make sure your `getTaskPilot()` method has the proper return type to prevent such mishaps.

Comment: thank you. @Mike S. can you like elaborate it? i created an interface to get the data. do i need to create the interfaces as an object?

Comment: Please post error text instead of links or images of errors. Eventually the link will expire, removing important information from your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot map trough object properties directly in angular template.

Unfortunately, ngFor only accepts 'of' and not 'in'. But fear not, you can do this:

add a simple method to get the keys of an object as array:

```
keys<T extends any>(obj:T):(keyof T)[]{
  return Object.keys(obj) as (keyof T)[];
}
```

then you can use the for loop with it:

```
<div *ngFor="let prop of keys(taskpilot)">
    {{prop}}: {{taskpilot[prop]}}
</div>
```

EDIT:

You could also simply use the existing keyvalue pipe.

```
<div *ngFor="let prop of taskpilot | keyvalue">
    {{prop.key}}: {{prop.value}}
</div>
```

Comment: While I answered the original question "Map through an object", looking more closely to your post and Mike's comment, you are indeed receiving an object in `response` instead of an array as you expect. So I'd check this part closely.

Comment: yeah i realize that i am receiving an object. but then how can I receive the object or rather access the properties of the object

Comment: + you could write an angular pipe containing this code

Comment: @Pieterjan you are right, and reminded me that there is already one... `keyvalue` returns an array of {key,value} for each of the objects enumerable properties.